# Does fossil have an equivalent of cvs status?

Tags: cvs, fossil

If possible, I would like to get the fossil equivalent of CVS's notion of Working revision:

```
===================================================================
File: tony              Status: Locally Modified

   Working revision:    1.2 2022-08-24 22:15:36 -0700
   Repository revision: 1.2 /cvsroot/kn/newdir/tony,v
   Commit Identifier:   1006307057632F6D41E
   Sticky Tag:      (none)
   Sticky Date:     (none)
   Sticky Options:  (none)
```

I am aware that there is a fossil status command, but that does not give any information about specific files in the repository. The `fossil finfo <file>` command shows the revisions, `fossil ls -v` & `fossil update -n` show some file status (like UPDATE, EDITED, etc.) but I can find no command that indicates the provenance of the file as in the "Working revision:    1.2" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to understand at least one big difference between pure CVS and modern VCS: **revisions of single files** vs **changesets for the whole repository**
2. Consequence from p1 - all files in repo in *given revision* (aka "changesets") belong to *this revision*

Maybe a sample of a such snippet (or any part of it) will provide the closest information to the required for you (paths, file and slashes are specific to my Windows-setup)

```
..\fossil finfo -s Makefile.classic && ..\fossil finfo -b -n 1 Makefile.classic
unchanged  6721c654a9
8d78edddf7 2022-01-21 george search-t Merge from trunk
```

- With `finfo -s` I get status of file and revision of Working Dir
- With `finfo -b -n 1` I get last single changeset, which touched file in the past

Comment: (In particular the finfo -s <file> command.)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does "provenance" mean in this context?

The [`annotate`](https://www.fossil-scm.org/home/help?cmd=annotate) command will show in which commits said file has been changed, but it will do so for every separate line in the file.

Comment: For example, in the above I would like to get the 1.2. If I reverted to 1.1, I would like to get 1.1. I guess I am looking for what version the current contents are 'based' on, if that makes sense.